# How to get Audience working?

Tags: audience

So the default video player audience I am confused about! How can I get it to be useful? Out of the box it isn't able to play public videos or even my go pro videos! If I download VLC that seems to work well but videos isn't working right? What do I do to make it work? Can you make it work out of the box a little better or is that part of the open source media law?

Comment: What file format are the videos you're trying to play? Needs more info to diagnose the problem

Comment: The error says "oops sorry missing ORI set. The format of the video is MP4, And it runs fine in VLC.

Answer (score 5):

Due to US patent law, elementary is not able to freely distribute codecs for many popular media formats. You will likely need to purchase a license for the codecs [from Fluendo on their website](http://www.oneplaydirect.com/oneplay/oneplay-codec-pack/).

However, if you're in a country where you are not affected by this patent law, you can install a set of codecs provided by Canonical with the following command in Terminal:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

VLC is outside of US jurisdiction, so they are able to distribute codecs in accordance with French patent law.

Comment: Is it illegal to use the VLC in the U.S.?

Comment: Due to US *copyright* law? Uh? And what software does Debian dare to distribute but not elementary?

Comment: So... Does that mean yea or no?

Comment: Tbh this is a new question. New questions shouldn't be asked in comments. It's unclear to me what your obligations are downloading and using VLC as an end user in the US. @Gilles I'm not a lawyer, but since elementary is a US company, we need to comply with US copyright law.

Comment: Afaik because of US patent law (not copyright law) it's illegal to *distribute* the patented codecs without paying fees for the licence, but not to download and use as an end-user.

Comment: @quassy oops, you're right. Editing to be "patent" not "copyright"